# How to do induction differently?

Tags: coq

I am doing an exercise in Coq and trying to prove if a list equals to its reverse, it's a palindrome. Here is how I define palindromes:

```
Inductive pal {X : Type} : list X -> Prop :=
  | emptypal : pal []
  | singlpal : forall x, pal [x]
  | inducpal : forall x l, pal l -> pal (x :: l ++ [x]).
```

Here is the theorem:

```
Theorem palindrome3 : forall {X : Type} (l : list X),
  l = rev l -> pal l.
```

According to my definition, I will need to do the induction my extracting the front and tail element but apparently coq won't let me do it, and if I force it to do so, it gives an induction result that definitely doesn't make any sense:

```
Proof.
  intros X l H. remember (rev l) as rl. induction l, rl.
  - apply emptypal.
  - inversion H.
  - inversion H.
  - (* stuck *)
```

context:

```
1 subgoals
X : Type
x : X
l : list X
x0 : X
rl : list X
Heqrl : x0 :: rl = rev (x :: l)
H : x :: l = x0 :: rl
IHl : x0 :: rl = rev l -> l = x0 :: rl -> pal l
______________________________________(1/1)
pal (x :: l)
```

aparently the inductive context is terribly wrong. is there any way I can fix the induction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I propose here is probably not the shortest one, but I think it is rather natural.

My solution consists in defining an induction principle on `list` specialized to your problem.

Consider natural numbers. There is not only the standard induction `nat_ind` where you prove `P 0` and `forall n, P n -> P (S n)`. But there are other induction schemes, e.g., the strong induction [`lt_wf_ind`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Arith.Wf_nat.html#lt_wf_ind), or the two-step induction where you prove `P 0`, `P 1` and `forall n, P n -> P (S (S n))`. If the standard induction scheme is not strong enough to prove the property you want, you can try another one.

We can do the same for lists. If the standard induction scheme `list_ind` is not enough, we can write another one that works. In this idea, we define for lists an induction principle similar to the two-step induction on `nat` (and we will prove the validity of this induction scheme using the two-step induction on `nat`), where we need to prove three cases: `P []`, `forall x, P [x]` and `forall x l x', P l -> P (x :: l ++ [x'])`. The proof of this scheme is the difficult part. Applying it to deduce your theorem is quite straightforward.

I don't know if the two-step induction scheme is part of the standard library, so I introduce it as an axiom.

```
Axiom nat_ind2 : forall P : nat -> Prop, P 0 -> P 1 ->
  (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S (S n))) -> forall n : nat, P n.
```

Then we prove the induction scheme we want.

```
Lemma list_ind2 : forall {A} (P : list A -> Prop) (P_nil : P [])
  (P_single : forall x, P [x])
  (P_cons_snoc : forall x l x', P l -> P (x :: l ++ [x'])),
  forall l, P l.
Proof.
  intros. remember (length l) as n. symmetry in Heqn. revert dependent l.
  induction n using nat_ind2; intros.
  - apply length_zero_iff_nil in Heqn. subst l. apply P_nil.
  - destruct l; [discriminate|]. simpl in Heqn. inversion Heqn; subst.
    apply length_zero_iff_nil in H0. subst l. apply P_single.
  - destruct l; [discriminate|]. simpl in Heqn.
    inversion Heqn; subst. pose proof (rev_involutive l) as Hinv.
    destruct (rev l). destruct l; discriminate. simpl in Hinv. subst l.
    rewrite app_length in H0.
    rewrite PeanoNat.Nat.add_comm in H0. simpl in H0. inversion H0.
    apply P_cons_snoc. apply IHn. assumption.
Qed.
```

You should be able to conclude quite easily using this induction principle.

```
Theorem palindrome3 : forall {X : Type} (l : list X),
  l = rev l -> pal l.
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, but this is an exercise from Software Foundations. A quote from preface: "Please do not post solutions to the exercises in public places: Software Foundations is widely used both for self-study and for
    university courses."

Comment: Yes, there is that induction principle in the standard library, see [`pair_induction`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract.NBase.html#NBaseProp.pair_induction)

Comment: holy jesus, that's brilliant.

Comment: @AntonTrunov you are right, this is a part of the exercise. but the problem is in the self study case, if i don't ask a question, how can i unblock myself? it's a learning material instead of a secret iq test, right?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I understand what you mean.I don't judge anyone and I don't have a ready answer for this case. Especially, if we take into account the fact that many people have posted their solutions to SF on github. I think Arthur Azevedo De Amorim is the final arbiter here (he is one of the authors).

Comment: If you think that's a problem, I can remove the proofs and just keep the big idea. Or if you have other ideas, they are welcome.

Comment: @eponier I would remove the proof of the final theorem `palindrome3` and keep the proof of the induction principle, what do you think?
@HuStmpHrrr please refrain from using "religious swearing" on this site ^^

Comment: @Zimmi48 I have removed the final proof as you suggested. But if the goal was to completely avoid leaking a solution of an exercise of Software Foundations, I am not sure it is enough though, since, as commented in my answer, the main idea is not there.

Comment: @eponier yeah well, I think it's fine. You cannot avoid communicating general ideas. How would you help people out?